# Simple remote access to another Mac or PC

Tags: remote-desktop

I frequently get asked by various poeple to fix or help them with their computers (Windows XP, Windows 7, OSX Leopard, OSX Snow Leopard, OSX Lion). What is currently the best secure, free (or cheap) and most imporantly simple way to remotely access the desktop of another Mac or PC over the internet from my Mac (OSX Lion).

It should be especially simple for the person at the other end asking for help because often they are not too computer-savvy. It should invlove nothing more than starting an application or enabling a checkbox in the settings. It would also be really nice if I could do remote access from my iPhone while I am on the go. It should also be possible to exchange files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look at [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) and it is free for [non-commercial users](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/kb/213-How-exactly-is-i-private-use-i-defined.aspx).

Comment: you can also download a quick support app that doesnt need to be installed - when its running you can connect, when you quit you cant

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look @ [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/products/free/)

Comment: LogMeIn is very expensive.

Comment: LogMeIn Free works fine for most users, and it's *free*. They have a paid service that's much more capable, but it's overkill for most folks.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look @ [RealVNC](http://www.realvnc.com/products/free/4.1/upgrade-notes.html), but it will be difficult for end user to set up permission on there router...

Comment: plus it will be difficult for the end user to tell me her IP adress.

Answer (score 0):

www.join.me
it's free and works with both macs and windows.